# Tensorflow assign sparse input over axis

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I have sparse data over one axis, e.g.

```
[[0,0,0],
 [1,2,3],
 [0,0,0],
 [0,0,0],
 [4,5,6]]
```

For efficiency, I would like to input batches in the format

```
sparse_axes = [1,4]
sparse_data = [[1,2,3],[4,6,6]]
```

and in tensorflow, de-sparse that data.

I know there is the function `tf.sparse` but that doesn't work over axes, which is inefficient in this case. Is there a function in tensorflow to do something like this:

```
> dense_data = tf.zeros((5,3))
> dense_data.assign(sparse_axes, sparse_data) # <--- this is the function I am looking for. 
> dense_data
[[0,0,0],
 [1,2,3],
 [0,0,0],
 [0,0,0],
 [4,5,6]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```
> sparse_axes = [1,4]
> sparse_data = [[1.0,2.0,3.0],[4.0,6.0,6.0]]
> dense_data = tf.IndexedSlices(
>     tf.Variable(sparse_data), sparse_axes, dense_shape=(5,3)
> )
> dense_data.dense_shape
[5,3]
> dense_data * tf.ones((5,3))
<tf.Tensor: shape=(5, 3), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 2., 3.],
       [0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.],
       [4., 6., 6.]], dtype=float32)>
```